# How to prove the dimension of the set of fixed points of tangent mapping of isometry is a constant?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Assume $\overline M$ is an $N$ dimensional differential manifold, and $\varphi: \overline{M} \to \overline{M}$ is isometric, if we define $M \triangleq \{ y \in \bar{M}: \varphi(y)=y \}$, then how can we check the following fact:

if we denote $A_x \triangleq \{ v \in T_x \overline{M}: (d\varphi) v=v \}$, then $\dim A_x$ is a constant as $x$ ranges a connected component of $M$.

Comment: Hint: The claim you are trying to prove is false, consider for instance $M$ which is the real projective plane with metric of constant curvature and $\varphi$ an isometric involution.

Comment: @MoisheKohan The claim is true if $x$ stays in a connected component. The fact is that the fixed points of $\varphi$ is a totally geodesic submanifold, hence the connected components are connected submanifolds and the tangent space is of constant dimension over connected components. The thing is to show the tangent space is exactly the set of vectors fixed by $\mathrm{d}\varphi$.